# How do i get the value in the register from gdb?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, disassembly

I am trying not to explode a bomb, From the screenshot, i have jumped the first explosion, now i have disassembled cmpl at x008048c14, the next instruction is ja which calls the explosion, which am trying to escape. 
So, what i understand is "cmpl $0x7, 0x1c(%esp)" subtracts 7 from 0x1c(%esp) then it sets up the flags, if ja is set then it explodes.

[image]

I tried to get information from the register by command "i r" and this is what i got, I'm trying to get what value is from 0x1c(%esp), i can't do "x/d 0xffffd000" How can i go about this?
[image]

Comment: Simply `x/d $esp-0x1c` should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some gdb tips, like layout asm / layout reg

Comment: I'm not sure how to retitle this, but the current title is obviously wrong (you already got the value *in* the register, and you're asking about the value pointed to by an effective-address).  Why doesn't dumping the memory at the address pointed to by esp work?